# Show this is the only $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $Q_8$ up to isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm very new to representation theory and trying to wrap my head around it. Specifically, I'm finding it hard to prove negative statements i.e. of the form *"there does not exist X"* because I'm finding the computations not too difficult but struggling with the theory.

By considering $Q_8$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{H}$ which can be viewed as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with basis $\{1, j \}$ I have arrived at the representation

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

of $Q_8$. ($A$ is the matrix representing $i$, $B$ represents $j$)

And then to show this is irreducible follows from the fact that there's no eigenvectors in common between these two matrices.

But how do I prove the negative of there's no more $2$-dimensional irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations up to isomorphism? If you can present it in such a way, a method that works in more general circumstances would be very helpful.

Comment: One way to proceed: every irreducible representation $V$ appears in the regular representation $\dim(V)$ times. There is the trivial representation, 3 sign representations, and 2 copies of the 2-dimensional representation you gave above. $1 + 3 + 2\cdot 2 = 8 = \#Q_8$, so those fill up the regular representation, showing that there's no room for other irreducible representations.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Thanks. I've not seen the result that every irreducible representation $V$ appears in the regular representation $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ times yet but after that it makes sense. I'll try think about how that could be proven.

Comment: Another way is to use the fact that tensor powers of any faithful representation will contain every irreducible representation, decompose $\rho^{\otimes 2}$ into irreducibles (for $\rho$ the $2$-dimensional representation) and argue by induction. More generally, if you're trying to show that a set $S$ of representations contains all the irreducibles, it suffices to show that for some faithful $\rho$ and for each $\sigma \in S$, $\rho \otimes \sigma$ can be decomposed into elements of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hands-on approach. We will use one representation theory fact: recall for any complex finite-dimensional representation of a finite group $G$, every operator $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable. (This follows from using Jordan canonical form from linear algebra.) Moreover, if $g$ has order $n$ then $\rho(g)$'s eigenvalues must evidently be $n$th roots of unity.

First let's consider $\rho(-1)$. Its eigenvalues must be $\pm1$. This gives three cases:

- $\rho(-1)=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\big]$. This would mean all $\rho(g)$s commute (why?) hence must be scalar transformations (why?) so all 1D subspaces are subreps. Contradiction.
- $\rho(-1)=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}1&\phantom{-}0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\big]$, up to change-of-basis. Since $-1$ commutes with all $g$s, $\rho(-1)$ commutes with all $\rho(g)$s, so this tells us the coordinate axes are subreps (why?). Contradiction.
- $\rho(-1)=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&\phantom{-}0\\\phantom{-}0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\big]$. (Conclusion.)

Next let's consider $\rho(\mathbf{i})$. Its eigenvalues must be $\pm i$. We again have cases:

- $\rho(\mathbf{i})=\pm\big[\begin{smallmatrix}i&0\\0&i\end{smallmatrix}\big]$. This is central, so commutes with $\rho(\mathbf{j})$, a contradiction. (How?)
- $\rho(\mathbf{i})=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}i&\phantom{-}0\\0&-i\end{smallmatrix}\big]$, up to change-of-basis. (Basis change cannot affect $\rho(-1)=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&\phantom{-}0\\\phantom{-}0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\big]$.)

Finally, consider $\rho(\mathbf{j})=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\big]$. Apply $\rho$ to $\mathbf{ij}=-\mathbf{ji}$ and solve for $a,b,c,d$ for $\rho(\mathbf{j})=\pm\big[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&\phantom{-}0\end{smallmatrix}\big]$. Use $\rho(\mathbf{i})$ as a change-of-basis matrix if necessary to ensure $\rho(\mathbf{j})=\big[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&\phantom{-}0\end{smallmatrix}\big]$. Since $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j}$ generate $Q_8$, this determines $\rho$, and we conclude $\rho$ must be the given matrix representation in some choice of coordinates.